# changing image src using inline onload takes too much CPU usage

Tags: html, image, cpu

Just curious to know why this line of code takes too much CPU ( as seen on console profiler )

```
<img style="display:none;" src="media/logo.png" 
     onload="this.style.display='block';this.src='media/dynamic_logo.png'" />
```

When I remove either `onload` event or `src` attribute, it does not take that much CPU. Could not understand whats going on there. Can anyone highlight

Answer (score 0):

Changing your image `src` attribute make the browser reload the image data, no wonder if the new `src` is the same as original.

In your example, this produces kind of a loop.

See this fiddle to understand the process (look at your browser js console):

https://jsfiddle.net/magikarp/d72ndk1e/

If you remove the `this.src [...]` from the `onload` attribute, console will prompt only one "onload is called".

Comment: Thanks . but the fiddle page is blank. I would be interested to look at the phenomena

Comment: Hi, sorry for being late, but as it could be usefull here ils the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/magikarp/d72ndk1e/2/